# Can't acccess Apache using ServerName

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host, intranet

I'm running a local Apache server with no access outside my network. I want to be able to navigate to sites by the server name.

For example, where `hostname` is my server's hostname and `home.lan` is my local domain,

- I **CAN** access Nextcloud using the *alias* via `https://hostname.home.lan/nextcloud`
- I **CANNOT** access Nextcloud using the *server name* via `https://nextcloud.hostname.home.lan`

What's wrong with my virtual host setup below?

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /nextcloud /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/
</IfModule>

...

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud
    ServerName nextcloud.hostname.home.lan
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does exactly happen when you try to access the server name? (And does the name exist in DNS?)

Comment: When I try to access using the server name, I get a server not found error, the same as visiting any other invalid URL. I didn't change anything in DNS.

Comment: I did some more digging after reading your comment and might know the issue. If I try to reach `hostname.home.lan`, I assume this is resolved in the router. And if I try to reach `nextcloud.hostname.home.lan` is the whole thing resolved in the router? In that case, I would need to update the router DNS to point the Nextcloud FQDN to the same hostname as the other FQDN.

Comment: Yes, the entire domain name is resolved via DNS before it can even get to your Apache server. Subdomains are not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using https, you need to have a VirtualHost entry which listens on port 443, not just 80.  You'll also need to specify relevant SSL directives for that VirtualHost block.

Also ensure that nextcloud.hostname.home.lan resolves to the proper IP address to be safe.

Comment: I tried using port 443 and got the same results, but good catch. I have the server certificate and key specified in the virtual host (updated answer with ellipsis for clarification). How would I check what nextcloud.hostname.home.lan resolves to since this is only on the internal network? Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle you can ping it (`ping nextcloud.hostname.home.lan`) from a command prompt / terminal / shell and see what it comes back with.

Comment: I get `Name or service not known`, likely because I don't have the proper DNS set up on the router as mentioned in the comments to the question. For some reason, none of the guides mention this step.